# How to declare an object variable properly? (about Classes and Subclasses)

Tags: polymorphism, action

When should I use each of these?

1.

```
Action whatever = new AbstractAction(){
    //whatever here...
};
```

or

2.

```
AbstractAction whatever = new AbstractAction(){
    //whatever here...
};
```

What's the difference? What is the standard way to go?